# How do I get Windows to print to two printers in a pooled, round-robin fashion?

Tags: windows-7, printer

I want to install 2 Photosmart Printers USB to my Laptop and print from Photoshop so that my printers are pooled and will work round robin

Comment: So, what is your problem?

Comment: I understand what the OP is trying to do. Let me compose an answer.

Comment: @MaQleod: ["What have you tried" by itself is not an acceptable comment.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122986/is-it-ok-to-leave-what-have-you-tried-comments "Meta Stack Exchange: Is it OK to leave "What have you tried?" comments?") Please try to use polite and constructive language, and ask for specific details if possible.

Answer (score 5):

#### Printer pooling is natively supported by Windows and can be enabled through the Printer Properties interface. Identical printers are needed for best results.

- Only one instance of the printer needs to be installed and listed in **Devices and Printers**. Windows will treat the printers as a single logical unit.
- Open **Devices and Printers** in **Control Panel**, then right-click on the printer in question and select **Printer properties**.
- In the **Ports** tab, check the **Enable printer pooling** checkbox, then select the printer ports to which the printers are connected.
- Windows will spread jobs evenly across the pooled printers. If you have large multi-page documents, you might want to submit two separate print jobs, each covering one half of the document, so that Windows can load-balance the printers. (If you have more printers, you may want to break the document down into more separate print jobs.)
- More information is available in **[this Microsoft TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958172.aspx)**.

[image: Printer properties dialog, allowing for printer pooling]

Comment: I have installed both printers, clicked on ports and enabled pooling.  I don't see the ink levels, sometimes the printout is cut off maybe only 1/2 inch or so.  I have to have this working perfectly in a couple of weeks.  In past I have used 2 computers but that takes more time and gets confusing.

Comment: Note: Windows will *not* spread the load evenly across the printers: it'll print to the first available port. If you only ever get one job at a time, the second printer will be largely idle.